Does the testcafe configuration file works for TestCafe Studio?
I have some test hooks and custom actions defined in .testcaferc.js file, these configurations are getting executed when I run the tests in the docker container.
We use testcafe Studio to generate the tests in .tectcafe formatted file. I would like to know how to configure testCafe Studio to read the .testcaferc.js file?
Thanks
I tried using the .testcaferc.js file but the tests executed from testCafe studio does not read those

The TestCafe configuration file doesn't work for TestCafe Studio.
The configuration in TestCafe Studio is set up by the Run Configurations dialog that is located in the main toolbar.
